# How to use String replace methods without replacing with empty Strings?

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace

I am loading a String from a csv file and trying to make an int array with it. The problem is I keep running into a `NumberFormatException` which is thrown when the program finds a `""` in the String array.

I don't need those empty Strings, I just want ints.

*Is there a way to avoid replacing characters with empty Strings?*

```
     aLine = aLine.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceFirst(",", "");
     aLine = aLine.replace(name, "").replaceAll("\"", "");

     final String[] strScores = aLine.split(",");

     final int[] scores = Arrays.stream(strScores)
                                 .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `filter` the stream for not empty and not `null` before you `parse`. Like,

```
final int[] scores = Arrays.stream(strScores)
        .filter(x -> x != null && !x.isEmpty())
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array list because you can easily add and remove

```
array_list<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // create array list

for (int i =0; i < array_string.length;i++){
    if (!string_array[i].equals("")){ // filter out empty
        array_list.add(string_array[i]);
    }
}

String new_string_array_without_empty = array_list.toArray(new String[0]); // convert to string array again
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather not add any data structures I don't need.

Comment: You are right. I am new to android development but decided to try to help anyways. Thanks for replying. :)